# Is it possible to list all files that are opened by a process

Tags: files, lsof

I know that `lsof` can list all files which are being opened by running processes.

If there is a process, which will open a file and then will be terminated, I don't think I can catch the file that is opened by the process with `lsof` because the process terminated itself too fast.

So I'm looking for such a tool (named `XXX`), allowing me to do the thing as below:

```
XXX ./my_process args
```

And the output of the command should be like this:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Which means that the `my_process` opens three files: `file1`, `file2` and `file3` while running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`strace`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html):

```
strace -e trace=open -o trace.log ./my_process args
```

Comment: This can't detect files opened by subprocesses.

Comment: I got 0 calls in the log, php turns out to use a different system call to open files, use `trace=open,creat,openat,openat2,name_to_handle_at` instead. (these are most of the system calls I could find which can open a file, I skipped the pcap ones) If it gives an error "invalid system call", remove that call from the list and try again.